# Interfering Vector in glBegin()

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to implement code for an assignment to render skeleton and mesh animations. In my glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) section, I have some vectors that appear to be interfering with my information when it shouldn't.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->nfaces.size(); i += 1)
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k += 1) {
          int j = k;//2 - k;

          glm::vec4 myPointPrime;

          myPointPrime.w = 1;



          myPoint.x = ecks = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][0];
          myPoint.y = why = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][1];
          myPoint.z = zed = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][2];



            // Stuff vvvv THIS CAUSES PROBLEMS
          for (int t = 0; t < mySkeleton->vertex.at(i).size(); t++) {
              myPointPrime += mySkeleton->vertex[i][j] * MyXformations * myPoint;
          }

          glNormal3f(mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][0],
                    mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][1],
                    mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][2]);


          glVertex3f(mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][0],
                    mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][1],
                    mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][2]);
         // glVertex3f(myPointPrime.x, myPointPrime.y, myPointPrime.z);
         // glVertex3f(myPoint.x, myPoint.y, myPoint.z);
    }
glEnd();
```

The myPointPrime += ... code is doing something weird to my Vertex calls, the scene won't render unless I comment out that for loop.

If I comment out the loop, then the scene renders, but I think I kinda need the loop if animating something like 16,000 vertexes is going to have any performance at all.

Is having that there kind of like having it automatically multiply with the glVertex calls?

Edit:

Below is another version of the code I hope should be more clear, instead of calculating the points in the actual drawing code I change the whole mesh to supposedly follow the skeleton each frame, but nothing is rendered.

```
for (int vertex_i = 0; vertex_i < mesh->nfaces.size(); vertex_i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k += 1) {
        int j = k;//2 - k;

        pointp.x = 0;
        pointp.y = 0;
        pointp.z = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < mySkeleton->vertex.at(vertex_i).size(); t++) {
            point.x = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][0];
            point.y = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][1];
            point.z = mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][2];

            //glPushMatrix();
            pointp += mySkeleton->vertex[vertex_i][t] * myTranslationMatrix * myRotationMatrix * point;

            cout << "PointP X: " << pointp.x << " PointP Y: " << pointp.y << " PointP Z: " << pointp.z << endl;
            mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][0] = pointp.x;
            mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][1] = pointp.y;
            mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[vertex_i][j]][2] = pointp.z;
            //myPointPrime += MyXformations * myPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that maybe the calculations for pointp isn't doing what I think its doing?

mySkeleton->vertex[vertex_i][t] is a vector from my 'skeleton' class, it holds all of the weights for every vertex, there are 17 weights per vertex.

"MyXformations" is a 4x4 matrix passed from my skeleton animation function that holds the last known key frame and this is applied to the vertexes.

point is the current point in the vertex.

Comment: Arrgh, why are you using immediate mode in the first place? Your data is already in a format that's perfectly suitable for being used in Vertex Array Object. And the skeletal animation should be done using a vertex shader.

Comment: That's how the course is structured.

Comment: Then please tell your teacher that 1998 called and it wants its immediate mode back. Immediate mode has been deprecated for well over 15 years; it should not be used for any new programs whatsoever and any second spent on teaching it is a second wasted. Plans to remove it entirely have been around since 2002 and were followed through with the release of OpenGL-3 in 2008. You can't use immediate mode in OpenGL-ES (mobile devices) and neither can you in WebGL (i.e. in Webbrowser based applications). Also teaching immediate mode proliferates misconceptions about what vertices are.

Comment: I'm aware, but I kind of don't have the time or energy to completely rewrite the Professor's code (that our assignments are based on) to use modern openGL; I tried for the first assignment and ended up having to give up and barely got most of the assignment completed. Its a Computer Graphics course that happens to use Opengl, its not an OpenGL course that happens to teach computer graphics. I'm trying to do Linear Blend Skinning using this formula http://i.imgur.com/7j3KM7h.png but I'm not sure if I even understood the formula right.

Comment: Actually that equation is rather simple to understand. But just for exercise: Tell me in your words, what do you think it means?

Comment: p prime is the sum of: [weights for bone(i) of my vertex p]*[Translation*Rotation for a given bone(i)]*[some original vertex point p in my mesh]; I've managed to eventually figure something out but it runs excruciatingly slowly.

Comment: You got it right. Yes, it runs slowly, because you're not able to harness the power of the GPU. There are number of tricks that make it run faster on the CPU, but it's easier and more efficient to just write a vertex shader and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop variable is `t`. However, you refer to `j` in the loop. Looks to me like your loop might simply be crashing for larger values of `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `t` inside the for loop. Is this expected?

`mySkeleton->vertex[i][j]` looks like it's out of bounds since `j` should be for `mesh->faces`/`mesh->nfaces`.

Also you can use `glNormal3fv` and `glVertex3fv` with arrays.

With out of bounds memory operations you can get all sorts of weird stuff happening, although I can't see any out of bound writes. Your `*` operators don't modify the objects do they?

If you're worried about performance. You shouldn't be using immediate mode. Instead, put all your data on the GPU with buffer objects (including join/bone transformations) and animate on the fly in the vertex shader.

This is from a few years ago, but worth a read: [Animated Crowd Rendering](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch02.html).

Comment: I went and fixed the issue with the incorrect counter variables but it still leaves me with an unrendered scene. I'm trying to have a mesh follow my skeleton (the skeleton works) to have my model be animated. I'm doing this by having "point prime is the sum of: weight(i) * xformations * point(i)" where "*" I assume is matrix multiplication. I'll add an addendum to my original post with the code being more clear I hope.